# How to load an image every second using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, phpgraphlib

I have programmed a web site in HTML/PHP/Javascript that must display the data stored in a MySQL database every second. It displays it as a graph (PNG image produced by running `graph.php`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <title>Live Tracking Run'INSA</title>
 
 <head>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
   function refresh() {
    document.getElementById('graph').src = 'graph.php';
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <p><h2>Visualisation des données</h2></p>
 
 <body onLoad='setInterval(refresh, 1000);'>
  <img id='graph'/>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

`visualiser.php` displays the graph well, but `graph.php` does not update the last one as it is supposed to.

PS: The graph (made with pChart libraries) shows the heart rate as a function of time as well.

Comment: On a side note, you should fix up your HTML structure. Basically `<head>` and `<body>` should be the only direct children of `<html>`. So put the `<title>` into the `<head>` and all the visual elements, like `<p><h2>...` inside your `<body>` :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally that looks fine. I suspect the image isn't being updated because the `src` isn't *changing* when you set it the second, third, etc. times. You could either clear it before setting it:

```
function refresh() {
    var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
    graph.src = '';
    graph.src = 'graph.php';
}
```

...or give it an ever-changing URL by appending a query string:

```
function refresh() {
    document.getElementById('graph').src = 'graph.php?' + Date.now();
}
```

Comment: look at this e.g https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb  no need to set src to null

Comment: Awesome ! The second solution works wonderfully ! Thank you very much !!

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar: That's toggling the src between two distinct values. The OP here is just re-asserting the same src every second. That's why setting `src` to `''` (not `null`) could help in this case (depending on caching settings; it may also be necessary to set it to `''` and then wait to set it to something else until after a `setTimeout(..., 0)`, but the query string solution makes doing that unnecessary).